how can do nested laravel transaction
I am using laravel to store records and other operations. My code is:
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
    
    // Start step 1
    if($request->steps == 'step1')
    {
        $filteredKeywords = array_filter($request->keywords, function ($value) {
            // Remove null values from the array
            return $value !== null;
        });
        $uniquen_number = $this->generateUniqueNumber();
        $videoupload = new Videoupload();
        $videoupload->user_id = Auth::id();
        $videoupload->unique_number = $uniquen_number;
        $videoupload->videostatus_id = 1;
        $videoupload->videotype_id = $request->videotype_id;
        $videoupload->videosubtype_id = $request->videosubtype_id;
        $videoupload->majorcategory_id = $request->majorcategory_id;
        $videoupload->subcategory_id = json_encode($request->subcategory_id);
        $videoupload->video_title = $request->video_title;
        $videoupload->keywords = json_encode($filteredKeywords);
        $videoupload->references = $request->references;
        $videoupload->abstract = $request->abstract;
        $videoupload->declaration_of_interests1 = $request->declaration_of_interests;
        $videoupload->acknowledge = $request->acknowledge;
        $videoupload->doi_link = $request->doi_link;
        if($videoupload->declaration_of_interests1 == 2)
        {
            $videoupload->declaration_remark = $request->declaration_remark;
        }  
        $videoupload->membershipplan_id = $request->membershipplan_id;
        $videoupload->terms_n_conditions = $request->terms_n_conditions;
        $videoupload->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'progress','steps'=>'step2','videoid'=>$videoupload->id,'message' => 'm1']);
    }
    // End step 1

    if($request->hasFile('vide_Upload')){

        // Start step 2
        if($request->steps == 'step2')
        {
            $video_details_step2 = single_video_details_without_join($request->videoid);
            $uniquen_number = $video_details_step2->unique_number;
            $major_category_details = get_majorcategories($request->majorcategory_id);
            $folderName = str_replace(' ', '_', $major_category_details->category_name);
            $vide_Upload2_image = $request->file('vide_Upload');
            $extension = $vide_Upload2_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $newFileName = $uniquen_number . '.' . $extension;
            $filePath = $vide_Upload2_image->storeAs('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number, $newFileName, 'public');
            $video_path_url = asset(Storage::url($filePath));

            $video_upload_step2 = Videoupload::find($request->videoid);
            $video_upload_step2->full_video_url = $video_path_url;
            $video_upload_step2->main_folder_name = 'Videos_to_Revise';
            $video_upload_step2->category_folder_name = $folderName;
            $video_upload_step2->uploaded_video = $newFileName;
            $video_upload_step2->save();
            DB::commit();
            return response()->json(['success'=>'progress','steps'=>'step3','videoid'=>$request->videoid,'message' => 'm2']);
        }

        if($request->steps == 'step3')
        {
            $video_details_step3 = single_video_details_without_join($request->videoid);
            $folderName = $video_details_step3->category_folder_name;
            $uniquen_number = $video_details_step3->unique_number;
            $newFileName = $video_details_step3->uploaded_video;

            $vide_Upload2_image_step3 = $request->file('vide_Upload');
            $extension_step3 = $vide_Upload2_image_step3->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $newFileName_cropped_file = $uniquen_number . '_cropped.' . $extension_step3;
        // Start crop the video
            $video_path = storage_path('app/public/uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number.'/'.$newFileName);
            $croppedVideoPath = storage_path('app/public/uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number.'/'.$newFileName_cropped_file);
            $cropped_video_path_url = url('/storage/uploads/Videos_to_Revise/' . $folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number . '/' . $newFileName_cropped_file);
        
            //$ffmpegCommand = "C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i " . $video_path . " -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:20 " . $croppedVideoPath;
            $ffmpegCommand = "ffmpeg -i " . $video_path . " -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:45 " . $croppedVideoPath;
            $test = exec($ffmpegCommand);

            $video_upload_step3 = Videoupload::find($request->videoid);
            $video_upload_step3->short_video_url = $cropped_video_path_url;
            $video_upload_step3->save();
        // End crop the video
        return response()->json(['success'=>'progress','steps'=>'step4','videoid'=>$request->videoid,'message' => 'm3']);
        }

        if($request->steps == 'step4')
        {
            $video_details_step4 = single_video_details_without_join($request->videoid);
            $folderName = $video_details_step4->category_folder_name;
            $uniquen_number = $video_details_step4->unique_number;
            $newFileName = $video_details_step4->uploaded_video;                

            $vide_Upload2_image_step4 = $request->file('vide_Upload');
            $extension_step4 = $vide_Upload2_image_step4->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $newFileName_cropped_file = $uniquen_number . '_cropped.' . $extension_step4;

            $filePath = 'uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number.'/'.$newFileName;
        // start encrypting the videos
        $highBitrate = (new X264)->setKiloBitrate(1000);
        //start encrypting fulllength files
        FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
            ->open($filePath) // Provide the path relative to the 'local' disk
            ->exportForHLS()
            ->withRotatingEncryptionKey(function ($filename, $contents) use ($folderName,$uniquen_number) {
                Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number . '/encrypted_files/' . $filename, $contents);
            })
            ->addFormat($highBitrate)
            ->save('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number . '/encrypted_files/'.$uniquen_number.'.m3u8');
        //end encrypting fulllength files
        //start encrypting cropped files
        FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
            ->open('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number.'/'.$newFileName_cropped_file) // Provide the path relative to the 'local' disk
            ->exportForHLS()
            ->withRotatingEncryptionKey(function ($filename, $contents) use ($folderName,$uniquen_number) {
                Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number . '/encrypted_files/' . $filename, $contents);
            })
            ->addFormat($highBitrate)
            ->save('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number . '/encrypted_files/'.$uniquen_number.'_cropped.m3u8');

        FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
            ->open('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number.'/'.$newFileName_cropped_file) // Provide the path relative to the 'local' disk
            ->getFrameFromSeconds(3)
            ->export()
            ->save('uploads/Videos_to_Revise/'.$folderName.'/'.$uniquen_number . '/'.$uniquen_number.'_screenshot.webp');
        //end encrypting cropped files
        // end encrypting the videos
        return response()->json(['success'=>'progress','steps'=>'step5','videoid'=>$request->videoid,'message' => 'm4']);
        }
    }
    //$videoupload->save();
    if($request->steps == 'step5')
    {
        $video_details_step5 = single_video_details_without_join($request->videoid);
        // Assuming $data is the array you provided
        $data = $request->name;

        $user_details = User::find(Auth::id());
        $user_details->role_id = 2; // Change role from member to author
        $user_details->save();

        $check_role = Userrole::where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('role_id',2)->first(); 
        // 2 means author       
        if(empty($check_role))
        {
            $courseoffer = Userrole::updateOrCreate([                            
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'role_id' => 2,                                 
            ],[                                
                'role_id' => 2,                        
            ]);
        }
        $check_role_corresponding_author = Userrole::where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('role_id',7)->first(); 
        // 2 means author       
        if(empty($check_role_corresponding_author))
        {
            $courseoffer = Userrole::updateOrCreate([                            
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'role_id' => 7,                                 
            ],[                                
                'role_id' => 7,                        
            ]);
        }

        $check_highest_priority = check_highest_priority($request->majorcategory_id);
        if ($check_highest_priority) 
        {
            $get_eligible_editorial_member = $check_highest_priority->user_id;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $get_eligible_editorial_member = get_eligible_user($request->majorcategory_id,$request->subcategory_id);
            if (is_object($get_eligible_editorial_member)) 
            {
                $get_eligible_editorial_member = $get_eligible_editorial_member->send_to_user_id;
            }
            else
            {
                $get_eligible_editorial_member = $get_eligible_editorial_member;
            }
        }
        
        // Start save into history table        
        $videohistory = new videohistory();
        $videohistory->videoupload_id = $video_details_step5->id;
        $videohistory->videohistorystatus_id = 1; // from videohistorystatuses table
        $videohistory->send_from_user_id = Auth::id();
        $videohistory->send_to_user_id = $get_eligible_editorial_member;
        $videohistory->send_from_as = 'Author';
        $videohistory->send_to_as = 'editorial-member';
        //$videohistory->send_to_as = 'editor-in-chief';
        $videohistory->save();
        // End save into history table
        $request->session()->flash('success', 'Record saved successfully.');
        $request->session()->flash('videoid', $video_details_step5->unique_number);
    }
    DB::commit();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Successfully','redirect' => route('my.account')]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Rollback the transaction if any operation fails
        DB::rollBack();

        // Log or handle the exception
        // For example:
        // Log::error($e->getMessage());

        // Return error response
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}

In the code. I have to send step wise messages. Like, if one step completes then user will see one step is completed like that.
For this, I've added different-different response after completing each step and then call again the store method.
Everything is good.
But I need transaction's rollback. Means if there occurs any error into any step then all the record must be rollback.
But currently, the record of current step is rolled back, not the transactions of previous step.
Means, if step1 is successfully completed then it will go on step2. Then if any error occurs in the step2, then only step2 records are being rolled back. And records of step1 is not being rolled back. How can I roll back all the transaction?

If steps are performed through distinct HTTP requests, then you can't have a single database transaction, which means you can't rollback previous steps.

okay @Olivier, so can I do different approaches for the step wise messages and also can rollback previous steps?

@vinod in your particular case it doesn't seem to hard to manually undo the previous steps e.g. if step 2 fails also delete the $videoupload that was created in step 1 and so on for each step. Typically if you have a multi-step process to create your data you might also consider somehow marking the records created as "draft" or "temporary" until the last step succeeds and then unmarking them so you can ignore the temporary records later and can also have some process to clear them up later. You can also allow your user to retry from where they left off

@apokryfos, Your idea seems good. I'll try and update to you. Thank you.

First an observation:
You can move the DB::beginTransaction(); into the try block as so...
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    try {
      DB::beginTransaction();
      // Start step 1
        if($request->steps == 'step1')
        {
          //the rest of your codes here

Another thing to consider is why you need to return a response after every step. If you need to do this then start and end transaction inside each step OR, you can have the return response from each step removed and have just one begin and commit transaction inside the try block.
Update:
In the general scope of what you want to implement, DB Transactions wont be of much help here because you have a return response after each step and each new call to the store() function doesnt keep track of the previous. You may explore using session storage or local storage in the frontend to temporarily hold data till the user completes all the steps or use a laravel cache service to temporarily hold all the steps till the final steps are done before calling the save method on all items. That way you can easily rollback everything if something breaks

Why would you do that?

If DB:beginTransaction() is inside the block and raises an exception because it failed, then DB::rollBack() will be executed, which makes no sense because you can't rollback a transaction that has not started.

check this: https://blog.hassam.dev/try-catch-with-db-transaction-in-laravel/ and other examples you can find. In some cases if you need to begin transaction outside the try block then commit should be after/under the catch block as seen here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/db-transaction-try-catch-swift-transportexception. Not sure if this is relevant to your issue, but just my observation @Olivier

Don't forget that the try block gets executed first and it only defaults to the catch when something fails so transaction already has started in the sense of it

@JimloveTM, I didn't get your solution. Can you please make me understand using my given code?

"so transaction already has started" Not if DB:beginTransaction() is inside the block and has failed.

@vinod DB Transactions wont be of help here because you have a return response after each step and each new call to the store() function doesnt keep track of the previous. You may explore using session storage or local storage in the frontend to temporarily hold data till the user completes all the steps or use a laravel cache service to temporarily hold all the steps till the final steps are done before calling the save method on all items. That way you can easily rollback everything if something breaks

okay @JimloveTM, got your point. I'll try.
